# REACT + DJANGO - CORS Errors After Login - CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

We have a React + Django application on GCP App Engine instances and we are facing a CORS error when fetching data through our REST API.

We have already installed and configured the CORS package for the Django Rest Framework in our django application:

`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com',
    'yyyyyyyyyyyy.appspot.com',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=[
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com',
    'https://yyyyyyyyyyyy.appspot.com',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS=True
```

`

The preflight request is successful as well as the application login, which performs an async request to our backend:

```
access-control-allow-origin: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com
access-control-allow-headers: accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with
access-control-allow-methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
access-control-max-age: 86400
```

The correct URL is passed through the allow-origins header. The actual GET request is then blocked with a 400 response code from the browser and the following error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxx.appspot.com/api/entities?page_size=10. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 400.

The strangest thing is that we are able to login into the application and that uses an async request to the same domain, only after we login does this error appear.

We have gone through several stackoverflow pages and different configurations (Eg. Using Regex in he allow ORIGINS configuration) but nothing seems to work, the application always returns the CORS error.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, we realized that the CORS error was actually masking another issue, related with the size of the cookies, that exceeded the allowed limit of the server.

The only way to view this error was to go to the network tab and preview the response data in Firefox, in Edge the response was empty, and we were not able to understand the real problem.